# Arch Linux: Is it possible to configure chromium to be my default browser for only a single website?

Tags: arch-linux, xdg-open, xdg

`xdg-settings get default-web-browser` produces `firefox.desktop`. This is what I want in almost every case. For a single website I want links to open in chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a wrapper script, make that the "default browser", check the URL in the script and then exec to either firefox or chrome.